# Convert div to canvas tag with html2canvas not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to convert div to jpg image,
Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="widget" class="widget"  >

    <div ng-show="userNum!=null" class="inputfieldwrapper buttonprint right col-sm-6  col-sm-push-6   horizontalinputfieldwrapper ">
        <label id="userNumLbl" for="disForUserNum" class=" font-bold col-lg-5 col-lg-push-7 col-md-5 col-md-push-7 col-xs-push-8" ng-bind="'מספר משלם:'"></label>
        <div class="inputContainer col-lg-7 col-lg-pull-4 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5 col-xs-pull-0 col-xs-pull-1 col-xs-3">
            <label ng-model="userNum" class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-7 col-md-5 col-md-push-7 col-xs-push-8" ng-bind="userNum"></label>
        </div>

    </div>



</div>
```

Also I have button and div to put the created image in my body:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG" />
<div id="img-out"></div>
```

In my js file I added click a function to this button:

```
$(function () {
            $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                html2canvas($("#widget"), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                        // Convert and download as image 
                        Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(canvas);
                         $("#img-out").append(canvas);


                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

I see some code that working fine in this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/

In this link - the span converted to canvas and appended to the end of the body.
My problem is that the image not include all my div's elements, It's only create some printscreen image,

What wrong in my code?

Thank you!!!

Comment: My project using angular js so I added it because it can affect on my problem, Do you think that I need to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the html2canvas.js file, I download it from :https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases

Thank you!! :)